# Programmatically create static block and add it to selected store views

Tags: magento2, store-view, static-block, cms-block

I need to create static blocks programmatically. How to assign a block to selected store views?

I've found tutorials about creating static blocks, but they all add the block to all store views, like this:

```
public function createCmsBlock()
{
    // $this->blockFactory is of type: \Magento\Cms\Model\BlockFactory
    $cmsBlock = $this->blockFactory->create();
    $cmsBlock->setIdentifier('block-identifier')
        ->setTitle('Block Title')
        ->setContent('Block Content')
        ->setIsActive(true)
        ->setStores([0]);
    $cmsBlock->save();
}
```

As far as I understand the line `->setStores([0]);` adds the block to all store views. But how to force it to add our block **only to selected store views**? And how to retrieve list of such store views?

Comment: https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/127495/how-to-add-a-cms-block-programmatically-in-magento-2. U need to get current store view & use that. `Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface` from u get storeId

Comment: The ->setStores([0]), add a comma and add your specific store ID here to associate with specific store only.

Answer (score -1):

An easy approach to do this is from the Admin Panel:

Content > Blocks > Edit (The Block in Question)

In the edit page you will see it's assigned to all stores/website. Use Ctrl key and select the stores you want it to display.

You can use the same approach to assign different text/language to different store views buy creating another block with same identifier but different content and assigned to different store-views.