# Creating static block by custom module magento2

Tags: magento2, static-block

How to create a Static block for custom module creation in magento2

Thanks

Comment: You mean cms block?

Comment: Yes mohamed, i wants to create a static block

Comment: Ok you want create cms block in the same time when you install a custom module?

Comment: https://www.google.fr/amp/www.herveguetin.com/create-cms-blocks-and-pages-programmatically/amp/

Comment: Ok thanks, i will check it and confirm mohamad

Answer (score 1):

Try this in your install/upgrade script.

```
<?php 

...

private $blockFactory;

public function __construct(
    \Magento\Cms\Model\BlockFactory $blockFactory
  )
{
    $this->blockFactory = $blockFactory;
}

...
...

$testBlock = [
    'title' => 'Test block title',
    'identifier' => 'test-block',
    'stores' => [0],
    'is_active' => 1,
    'content' => 'Test block content'
];
$this->blockFactory->create()->setData($testBlock)->save();
```

[Reference](https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/127499/48571)

Comment: how to update if block is present already?