# Magento 2 how create CMS page programmatically

Tags: magento2, magento2.2, magento2.3, magento2.3.0

I need any query or code to create CMS page programmatically, Please help me or suggest me if any module available for the same.

Thanks :)

Comment: @VishwasBhatnagar Create CMS pages and Block are same ?

Comment: Sorry i misread  the question , But you can just google it before posting a question,  https://naruniec.me/magento/magento-2-add-cms-page-programmatically/

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Create CMS Page By Installer In Magento 2 – Before you start you must have knowledge of Magento 2 custom module creation, So create your custom module first.

Here I’m going to explain you how you can create CMS page by installer in magento 2.
First of all create a “InstallData.php” file on location Vendor\Module\Setup then use below code.

```
<?php

namespace Kodefolks\Cmsinstaller\Setup;

use Magento\Cms\Model\PageFactory;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\InstallDataInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleContextInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleDataSetupInterface;

class InstallData implements InstallDataInterface
{
    private $pageFactory;
    private $blockFactory;

    public function __construct(PageFactory $pageFactory)
    {
        $this->pageFactory = $pageFactory;
    }

    public function install(ModuleDataSetupInterface $setup, ModuleContextInterface $context)
    {
        $cmsPageData = [
            'title' => 'Custom cms page', // cms page title
            'page_layout' => '1column', // cms page layout
            'meta_keywords' => 'Page keywords', // cms page meta keywords
            'meta_description' => 'Page description', // cms page description
            'identifier' => 'custom-page', // cms page url identifier
            'content_heading' => 'Custom cms page', // Page heading
            'content' => "<h1>Write your custom cms page content.......</h1>", // page content
            'is_active' => 1, // define active status
            'stores' => [0], // assign to stores
            'sort_order' => 0 // page sort order
        ];

        // create page
        $this->pageFactory->create()->setData($cmsPageData)->save();
    }
}
```

In this way we can create CMS page programmatically by installer file.

Thanks :)

Comment: The ```save()``` method has been deprecated in version ```2.3.4``` you have to use the ```BlockRepository``` instead of the ```PageFactory```.

Comment: @MathanagopalS in this case `PageRepository` but yes.

Answer (score 5):

Try this

```
<?php 

...

private $pageFactory;

public function __construct(
    \Magento\Cms\Model\PageFactory $pageFactory
  )
{
    $this->pageFactory = $pageFactory;
}

...

...

    $testPage = [
     'title' => 'Test page title',
     'identifier' => 'test-page',
     'stores' => [0],
     'is_active' => 1,
     'content_heading' => 'Test page heading',
     'content' => 'Test page content',
     'page_layout' => '1column'
    ];

$this->pageFactory->create()->setData($testPage)->save();
```

[Reference](https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/127499/48571)