# Link Custom Block to custom page

Tags: layout, blocks, custom, page, view

I created a custom block and was able to link to it on the home page or display it there. Unfortunately I don't get the block displayed on another page I created via the backend.
If I understand the whole thing correctly, do I have to change the name of the .xml created in the layout? 
This is how it works:
[image]

and that's how it doesn't work: 
[image]

Do you have any idea how I can get the second case working?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you have to Know about how layout file name should make.

**cms_index_index.xml**

Here

> cms is route name
>
> index is controller name
>
> index is controller action file name

Replace your required route and controller file.

> **Update**

**app/code/VendoreName/ModuleName/Controller/Index**

**Index.php**

```
<?php

namespace VendoreName\ModuleName\Controller\Index;

use Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context;
use Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory;
use Magento\Framework\App\Action\HttpPostActionInterface;
use Magento\Framework\App\Action\HttpGetActionInterface;
use Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action;

class Index extends Action implements HttpGetActionInterface, HttpPostActionInterface
{
    /**
     * @var PageFactory
     */
    protected $resultPageFactory;

    /**
     * @param Context $context
     * @param PageFactory $resultPageFactory
     */
    public function __construct(
        Context $context,
        PageFactory $resultPageFactory
    ) {
        $this->resultPageFactory = $resultPageFactory;
        parent::__construct($context);
    }

    /**
     * Default customer account page
     *
     * @return \Magento\Framework\View\Result\Page
     */
    public function execute()
    {
        echo "hellow";
        exit();
        //return $this->resultPageFactory->create();
    }
}
```

**app/code/VendoreName/ModuleName/view/frontend/layout**

**summary_index_index.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="2columns-left" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="page.main.title">
            <action method="setPageTitle">
                <argument translate="true" name="title" xsi:type="string">Summary Page</argument>
            </action>
        </referenceBlock>
        <referenceContainer name="content">

        </referenceContainer>
    </body>
</page>
```

**app/code/VendoreName/ModuleName/etc/frontend**

**routes.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>

<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:App/etc/routes.xsd">
    <router id="standard">
        <route frontName="summary" id="summary">        
            <module name="VendoreName_ModuleName"/>
        </route>
    </router>
</config>
```

Now run Magento command

```
php bin/magento s:up

php bin/magento s:s:d -f

php bin/magento c:c

php bin/magento c:f
```

and Clear your browser cache

> **url like : domain/summary**

***I Hope This Helps You.***

Comment: Many thanks for the answer. I have tried it and it also works with the URL:  cms/index/summary
But there is neither the layout nor the rest of the content of the summary page.

My goal would be that it is located within the cms page "summary", i.e. callable with the following URL: domain/summary
and there as a block as additional content. Could you help me with that?

Comment: please check my updated answer and update me

Comment: Hello again, thank you for the quick answers! I tested it immediately and the message "hellow" only appears on the "domain/summary/index" page. Am I doing something wrong or what else do I have to do? I'm sorry for the many questions, but I can't get on with this x.x

Comment: have you do all change of my above change ?

Comment: run magento command and check it

Comment: please update me .

Comment: I really don't know why, but it does not appear within the "domain/summary" page. Only on the "domain/summary/index" page. I really followed all of your steps including the Magento commands.

Comment: no it's works. clear cache ad run into private browser. try it's works

Comment: I've tried that... Do you think it's because of the Community Edition in version: 2.3.4?

Comment: No it's not vesion dependent

Comment: Are there perhaps special features with the two other files "module.xml" and "registration.php"? I tried again in an empty module and emptied the cache really several times, but it doesn't work for me.

Comment: I have just tested it by creating a coded summary page. With that it actually worked. But I need access to the page I created via the admin portal (Content -> Pages -> Summary). How would this access look like?

Comment: @Jackridder it's works then please accept and vote up

Comment: For your above requirement check this answer https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/127495/how-to-add-a-cms-block-programmatically-in-magento-2