# how to add cms block in magento without using our own theme and in app/code?

Tags: blocks, cms, code

How to Add CMS Block in Magento2 programatically.

I want to add a cms block in app/code insstead of app/design using layout or xml files.

Comment: Your original question is about added CMS block programmatically or something different you are looking?

Answer (score 0):

You can create in setup script or controller.

```
public $blockFactory;

public $blockRepository;

public function __construct(
    PageFactory $pageFactory,
    \Magento\Cms\Model\BlockFactory $blockFactory,
    \Magento\Cms\Model\BlockRepository $blockRepository
  )
{
    $this->resultPageFactory = $resultPageFactory;
    $this->blockFactory = $blockFactory;
    $this->blockRepository = $blockRepository;
}


yourfunction()
{
    $Page = [
    'title' => 'Your page title',
    'identifier' => 'your-page',
    'stores' => [0],
    'is_active' => 1,    
    'content' => 'test content',
    'page_layout' => '1column'
    ];

    $this->blockFactory->create()->setData($Page)->save();
}
```

Ref : [How to add a CMS block programmatically in Magento 2?](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/127495/how-to-add-a-cms-block-programmatically-in-magento-2/127499#127499)

Comment: I want to add header and footer using cms block through layout.xml and phtml only.

Answer (score 0):

Create a module like `app/code/VendorName/ModuleName/`

then create layout file `default.xml` at `app/code/VendorName/ModuleName/view/frontend/layout`

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
         <referenceContainer name="footer">
    <block class="Magento\Cms\Block\Block" name="Promo">
            <arguments>
                <argument name="block_id" xsi:type="string">{BlockIdenfier}</argument>
            </arguments>
    </block>
        </referenceContainer>
    </body>
</page>
```

Replace `{BlockIdenfier}`  with your cms block identifier.